# For a derived class with a constructor that takes a base class pointer, how do I refer to the base class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class, abstract-base-class

I'm working on an assignment on abstract base classes for shapes. For the last section we need to write a class which is a general 3D version of any of the prior 2D shapes eg. square.

So as you can see from my code below, its constructor takes a base class pointer `shape*`. In my function "`getVolume`" I basically need to multiply `z` by the area of the shape pointed to by `shape*`, which can be calculated by a function `getArea()` which is specified in each shapes respective class. But do I refer to the shape that is being pointed to?

```
class prism : public square, public rectangle, public circle {
private:
    double z;
public:
    prism(){z=0;}
    prism(shape*, double a){z=a;}
    ~prism(){cout<<"Prism destructor called"<<endl;}

    //Access functions
    void print_(){cout<<"Prism with length = "<<z;}
    double getLength(int n)const{ return z; }
    void setLength(double a){z=a;}

    //Other functions
    double getVolume(){ return ??????????;}

    };
```

How do I refer to the shape that is being pointed to? I was hoping it would be something like `this->getArea()` or `shape*->getArea()` but I just get errors that tell me "shape does not refer to a value" etc.

Can anyone offer some assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shape is a class type not an object. You should keep the pointer to shape in Your constructor. It should be like:

Your class member:

```
shape * theShape;
```

And your constructor:

```
prism(shape* sh, double a)
{
    z=a;
    theShape =sh;
}
```

And your getVolume() should be like:

```
double getVolume(){ return theShape->getArea()*z;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be reading your question wrong but you don't seem to be using the `shape*`. So you could add a member in your class:

```
shape* s_;

prism(shape* s, double a) s_(s) ...
```

And then call `s_->getArea()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sorry this was a fairly stupid question, but an easy mistake to make i guess. As you say I needed to add a `shape*` as a member of my prism class which I could then refer to in my constructor. For anyone running into a similar confusion here is what I believe a class of this sort should look like!

```
class prism : public ...(reference 'shapes')..... {
private:
    double z;
    shape* s;
public:   
    prism(shape* s_, double a){z=a; s=s_;}

    double doSomethingToShape(){return s->doSomething();}

};
```